# Grails - How to instantiate service in Controller when doing controller testing

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I am using a service in controller. I am writing unit test for the controller but I am unable to instantiate service in controller. It is always `null`.

if I instantiate service using `new` operator in Controller testing class. The services in the service class are not instantiated.

How can I instantiate a service in testing class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can let Spring do it for you.

A controller that depends on a service:

```
// grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy
package demo

class DemoController {
    def helperService

    def index() {
        def answer = helperService.theAnswer
        render "The answer is ${answer}"
    }
}
```

The service:

```
// grails-app/services/demo/HelperService.groovy
package demo

class HelperService {

    def getTheAnswer() {
        42
    }
}
```

A unit test which injects the service:

```
// src/test/groovy/demo/DemoControllerSpec.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(DemoController)
class DemoControllerSpec extends Specification {

    static doWithSpring = {
        helperService HelperService
    }

    void "test service injection"() {
        when:
        controller.index()

        then:
        response.text == 'The answer is 42'
    }
}
```

A unit test which injects a fake version of the service:

```
// src/test/groovy/demo/AnotherDemoControllerSpec.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(DemoController)
class AnotherDemoControllerSpec extends Specification {

    static doWithSpring = {
        helperService DummyHelper
    }

    void "test service injection"() {
        when:
        controller.index()

        then:
        response.text == 'The answer is 2112'
    }
}

class DummyHelper {

    def getTheAnswer() {
        2112
    }
}
```

Comment: If the service you are injecting has dependencies on other beans, those can also be rigged up in `doWithSpring`.

Comment: I am still getting `null` for the beans injected in service.

Comment: Give me a minute.  I will upload an example.

Comment: See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/serviceinjection.  The commit at https://github.com/jeffbrown/serviceinjection/commit/b09ab32615ede379c33e60355cab4e3e1a31b54c demonstrates one way to rig up one service that depends on another.

Comment: You can configure as many beans as necessary in the `doWithSpring` block.  Spring will auto wire your dependency tree arbitrarily deep but in a unit test one almost never needs more than 2 levels of dependencies rigged up.  You shouldn't have to construct a giant graph of objects for a unit test, but you could.